# Do I need to handle app updates in iOS for Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-cloud-messaging

We are using Google Cloud Messaging in our forms app. On the Android side, the app became unregistered when we did an update. We could not guarantee that the user would open our app after update, so we needed to handle this case.

I cannot determine if this will be an issue with iOS. Does anyone know if GCM handles an updated/replaced app on iOS better and we won't need extra code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Keeping the Registration State in Sync](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#keeping-the-registration-state-in-sync):

> To protect the client app and app server from potential malicious re-use of registration tokens, **you should periodically initiate token refresh** from the server. When GCM registration token refresh is initiated from server side, **the client app must handle a tokenRefreshed message** with the GCM registration client/server handshake.

For iOS, it was stated in [Handle refreshed tokens](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#handle-refreshed-tokens) that:

> To handle cases where the registration token has been refreshed, the `GGLInstanceIDDelegate` protocol declares an `onTokenRefresh` method that is called when the system determines that tokens need to be refreshed.

Sample code:

```
- (void)onTokenRefresh {
  // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
  NSLog(@"The GCM registration token needs to be changed.");
  [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                      scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                    options:_registrationOptions
                                                    handler:_registrationHandler];
}
AppDelegate.m
```

Furthermore, to handle token refreshes the client app should:

> 1. Declare a class that adopts the `GGLInstanceIDDelegate` protocol;
> 2. Set that class as delegate on the `GGLInstanceIDConfig` using the delegate property.

You may find additional references that can help in the given documentations.

Aside from that, this SO post - [Why re-register to gcm when application gets updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741183/why-re-register-to-gcm-when-application-gets-updated) has also explained why token refresh is required.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please help me understand: is onTokenRefresh fired when the app is updated? Or are you suggesting that the periodic refresh issued from the server side will mitigate the situation?